# How to split data from one column to three columns in another table? SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have table (inf) with two columns `id_student` and `hobbies` like this:

```
ID_student =  1      
Hobbies =   "music, cooking, bassguitar"
```

and I want to copy the hobbies by splitting them  to another table (hobbies) in three columns which contain the following columns:

```
ID_student   hobby1   hobby2     hobby3
1            music    cooking    bassguitar
```

how could I write something likethat in Postgres?

Comment: There always have maximum three hobbies ??

Comment: In a normalized model it should be three tables: list of students, list of possible hobbies, linking table (id_student, id_hobby). To parse your values you need splitting function (very common question, please use search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do this.
One way is using the [string_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) function:

```
INSERT INTO hobbies (id, hobby1, hobby2, hobby3) 
SELECT id,hobbies_array[1],hobbies_array[2],hobbies_array[3] FROM 
  (
    SELECT id,string_to_array(hobbies,',') AS hobbies_array 
    FROM inf
  ) AS foo;
```